# How to avoid "knp_menu.factory" deprecation?

Tags: knpmenubundle, symfony-3.3, knpmenu

I'm trying to use `KNPMenuBundle` with `Sumfony 3.3` but I'm getting this annoying warning:

> Autowiring services based on the types they implement is deprecated
>   since Symfony 3.3 and won't be supported in version 4.0. You should
>   rename (or alias) the "knp_menu.factory" service to
>   "Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface" instead.
>
> > Trace:
> >     {..../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/AutowirePass.php:344:
> >     }

I did not set this `knp_menu.factory` at all, probably it was automatically set by the bundle.

Do I need to configure anything to make this warning go away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it like this:

```
app.component_menu.builder:
    class: AppBundle\Component\Menu\Builder
    arguments: ['@knp_menu.factory', '@event_dispatcher']
    calls:
        - [setAuthorizationChecker, ['@security.authorization_checker']]


Knp\Menu\ItemInterface:
    class: Knp\Menu\MenuItem
    factory: ['@app.component_menu.builder', mainMenu]
    arguments: ['@knp_menu.matcher']
    tags:
        - { name: knp_menu.menu, alias: main }

Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface:
    alias: knp_menu.factory
    public: false
```

Not sure if this is the recommended resolution, but it removes the deprecation notices.