# Symfony 4 - KNP Menu - MenuBuilder not being called

Tags: php, symfony, knpmenubundle

I am upgrading from Symfony 3.3 to Symfony 4.

KNPMenu was running fine under Symfony 3.3, but now I am seeing this exception:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The
>   menu "main" is not defined.").

**services.yaml**

```
App\Menu\MenuBuilder:
    public: true
    tags:
        - { name: app.menu_builder.admin, method: createAdminMenu, alias: admin }
        - { name: app.menu_builder.calendar, method: createCalendarMenu, alias: calendar }
        - { name: app.menu_builder.main, method: createMainMenu, alias: main }
        - { name: app.menu_builder.trailer, method: createTrailerMenu, alias: trailer }
        - { name: app.menu_builder.user, method: createUserMenu, alias: user }
```

**MenuBuilder**

```
Namespace App\Menu;

use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class MenuBuilder implements ContainerAwareInterface
{

    use ContainerAwareTrait;

    private $factory;

    /**
     * @param FactoryInterface $factory
     */
    public function __construct( FactoryInterface $factory )
    {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }
```

I put a `die('here');` in the *__construct*, it is never executed.

Using *php bin/console debug:container menu* yields:

```
Information for Service "App\Menu\MenuBuilder"
==============================================

 ---------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Option           Value                                                                    
 ---------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Service ID       App\Menu\MenuBuilder                                                     
  Class            App\Menu\MenuBuilder                                                     
  Tags             app.menu_builder.admin (method: createAdminMenu, alias: admin)           
                   app.menu_builder.calendar (method: createCalendarMenu, alias: calendar)  
                   app.menu_builder.main (method: createMainMenu, alias: main)              
                   app.menu_builder.trailer (method: createTrailerMenu, alias: trailer)     
                   app.menu_builder.user (method: createUserMenu, alias: user)              
  Public           yes                                                                      
  Synthetic        no                                                                       
  Lazy             no                                                                       
  Shared           yes                                                                      
  Abstract         no                                                                       
  Autowired        yes                                                                      
  Autoconfigured   yes                                                                      
 ---------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I get MenuBuilder __construct to execute?

Comment: I think you should have updated to Symfony 3.4 first, to get every deprecation notices.

Comment: [Did you read this?](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_major.html)

Comment: What version of KNP menu do you use?

Comment: Try to set `autowired` and/or `autoconfigured` to false. Have a look to https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/menu_service.html to proprely register your menu service.

Comment: I read and followed the documentation, I am using Symfony Flex. With autowire and autoconfigure off it did not work either. I addressed all dependencies and there is only one deprecation notice. The default page is loading, with assets managed by webpack/encore.

Comment: @MathieuDormeval - I am registering a MenuBuilder as a service

Comment: If you set autowired to false, this must be an Exception because you don't set Factory parameters of service, like this : `arguments: ["@knp_menu.factory"]`

Comment: The argument was there when autowire was false

Comment: Is the others menus works ?

Comment: None of the menus work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your time.

This gist was helpful: https://gist.github.com/lsv/4d8044d21819f28f0dde52a3fb8211a0

This answer was helpful: [How to avoid "knp_menu.factory" deprecation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44922522/how-to-avoid-knp-menu-factory-deprecation?rq=1)

**services.yaml**

```
app.menu_builder:
    class: App\Menu\MenuBuilder

app.menu.main:
    class: Knp\Menu\MenuItem
    factory: ['@app.menu_builder', 'createMainMenu']
    arguments: { $options: [] }
    tags:
    - { name: knp_menu.menu, alias: main }
```

I used `php bin/console debug:autowiring security` to get the security authorization checker

Then I updated **MenuBuilder.php** like so:

```
Namespace App\Menu;

use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;

class MenuBuilder
{

    private $factory;
    private $security;

    /**
     * @param FactoryInterface $factory
     */
    public function __construct( FactoryInterface $factory, AuthorizationCheckerInterface $security )
    {
        $this->factory = $factory;
        $this->security = $security;
    }
```

Adding the SecurityAuthorizationChecker allows me to control the menu items offered with this statement:

```
if( $this->security->isGranted( 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY' ) )
```